# How to add a local Swift Package as a dependency to a framework's Cocoapods podspec?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have pod framework X that has a podspec and it has a dependency on a Swift package. The Swift package has been successfully added to the workspace of framework X (by simply dragging and dropping the folder to create the reference) and can be used for development of the framework.

The part that's a problem is finding a way to define that dependency on the package within the podspec so that when the pod is installed the swift package gets imported along with the framework.

Using source_files doesn't seem to be working:

`s.source_files = 'SwiftPackage/*', ...`

Comment: Found a cocoapods closed issue with same idea https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10463